# Swift Any Array not accessing Struct Methods

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

So, I have the following code in Swift 2:

```
struct IntToken {
    var value:Int

    init(val:Int) {
        self.value = val
    }

    mutating func add(val:IntToken) {
        self.value += val.value
    }
}

var table = [Any]()
table.append(IntToken(val:3))
table.append(IntToken(val:4))
table[0].add(table[1])
```

This gives me the following error

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/jx/bhltcyc90117d2wx_r82p4fr0000gn/T/./lldb/73237/playground71.swift:22:6: error: value of type 'Any' (aka 'protocol<>') has no member 'add'
table[0].add(table[1])
~~~~~^~~ ~~~
```

The issue is, I am trying to create an Array, that will contain different type of objects, not just `IntToken`'s, but I also want to be able to access the elements of that array and use their methods on one another. Whenever I try to use the Any array, however, it doesn't allow me to do this, because it's reading the accessed struct instance as an any type.

What's a good way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: try `enum Token { case IntToken(Int); case StringToken(String) }`

Comment: either you need to force downcast each array element or you need to have homogenous typed array

Comment: With using Enum you suggested i get this error:

Comment: Playground execution failed: /var/folders/jx/bhltcyc90117d2wx_r82p4fr0000gn/T/./lldb/73237/playground85.swift:20:14: error: cannot convert value of type 'IntToken' to expected argument type 'Token'
table.append(IntToken(val:3))
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jx/bhltcyc90117d2wx_r82p4fr0000gn/T/./lldb/73237/playground85.swift:21:14: error: cannot convert value of type 'IntToken' to expected argument type 'Token'
table.append(IntToken(val:4))
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jx/bhltcyc90117d2wx_r82p4fr0000gn/T/./lldb/73237/playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your original struct:

```
struct IntToken {
    var value:Int
    init(val:Int) {
        self.value = val
    }
    mutating func add(val:IntToken) {
        self.value += val.value
    }
}
```

Do like this:

```
var table = [Any]()
table.append(IntToken(val:3))
table.append(IntToken(val:4))
var it = table[0] as! IntToken // take it out with cast and var ref
it.add(table[1] as! IntToken) // add with cast; `it` is now IntToken(val:7)
table[0] = it // put it back in (if you want to)
```

Answer (score 0):

i slightly modified matt's answer (accepted answer) to show how to avoid crash in case some table element has other type as IntToken.

```
var table:[Any] = []

table.append(IntToken(val:3))
table.append(IntToken(val:4))
if let it0 = table[0] as? IntToken,
    let it1 = table[1] as? IntToken {
        var it0 = it0
        it0.add(it1)
        table[0] = it0
}
print(table) // [IntToken(value: 7), IntToken(value: 4)]
```

I prefer to modify your IntToken

```
struct IntToken {
    var value:Int

    func add1(token: IntToken)->IntToken {
        var token = token
        token.value += value
        return token
    }
}
```

and remove any 'mutating' function from it. Now the original code snippet could be modified to 'more functional' and easy to understand version

```
var table = [Any]()

table.append(IntToken(value:3))
table.append(IntToken(value:4))
if let it1 = table[1] as? IntToken,
    let v = (table[0] as? IntToken)?.add1(it1) {
    table[0] = v
}

print(table) // [IntToken(value: 7), IntToken(value: 4)]
```